# How to make sure composer version running on github action would same as composer version inside my docker container?

Tags: laravel, docker, github, composer-php, github-actions

I'm not really sure how github actions works when running their jobs. Currently i'm facing this condition:

- I have devilbox docker services that includes specific php version and also has composer with specific version.
- Currently i'm working laravel project with TDD and using artisan (php unit and laravel dusk) to do unit testing, integration testing, and browser testing (gui testing) automatically. Because i don't have PHP on my host machine, so artisan tests must be run inside the docker container, right?

So now, how to make sure I can run composer build/update, php artisan test also with laravel dusk inside the docker container to make sure the tools version used is based on the tools installed in the docker container?

I want to get to know how to make sure the tools version used in github actions is based on the tools installed in the docker container

Comment: Why is this relevant? You should not run `composer update` in the pipelines anyways, and `composer install` should behave equal in most versions

Comment: I'm sorry for the composer update thing. It is the php artisan test command or composer run test-suite command inside the container for github actions what i've concerned about

Comment: Then feel free to add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: In short: Use the same container. Compare: _[Creating a Docker container action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action)_ . But as you not even know if or not you need to run a container at all, this is just pure guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved to Sail instead of using devilbox and customize the defaul sail docker compose to be comply in the production environment. I also use complex bash script to prepare, install, overriding each docker compose in certain environments for the CI/CD pipeline.

Referring to [@hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre) answer in the comment:

> In short: Use the same container. Compare: Creating a [Docker container action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action). But as you not even know if or not you need to run a container at all, this is just pure guesswork.

I just have to run the same container with composer included in the image in the Github Action, it's simple and easy to use